# Salesforce streaming API: Getting events after network failure and before resubscribe

Tags: java, salesforce, cometd

I am looking for implementation of CDC(Change Data Capture) for Salesforce using Streaming APIs.
I have gone thorugh the documents that are provided and I am able to use the code provided in the documentation.
Through the code:

1-I am able to get the events at the client side for any change in Salesforce object.

2- While network failure I am able to reconnect and resubscribe the channel and able to get the  new events as suggested in the document.(through subscribe in handshake receive).

My question is, how to get those events which were generated after the network failure and before the resubscription?

I appriciate any help on this.

Comment: I used the provided extension in the documentation as well. The extension code itself had to be changed because of the version issue. The provided extension code was based on API 3 version and salesforce  supports API version 2.3.1. so I changed the code but still I am not getting the desired result. https://github.com/developerforce/StreamingReplayClientExtensions/issues/2

Comment: Am i  missing anything or no one has faced this issue?

Comment: I updated the streaming code to be compatible with  the provided extension version but it is still not working.It is still showing the events with are currently being updated as client code is connected and not showing the past 24 hours events based on the replayid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the datamap that   I was sending to the extension. I was using the "ReplayId" as key for sending the replayid. Correct key was channel name. Now everything works fine.